# How to form a file path in C# under Mono in Mac OS?

Tags: .net, mono, filepath

I am trying to execute

```
Process.Start(s);
```

in C# in Mono Framework (in Mac OS).

but it seems I am unable to build string s correctly using this code:

```
var appDataDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) +
Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + appName + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
var tempDir = appDataDir + "temp" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
var s = "file://" + tempDir + "test.html";
```

I am getting the following error: "Error while executing: file://C:\users\my_username\Application Data\my_app_name\temp\test.html. Message: DDE failure."

Comment: A few things you might want to revise your question. 1. There is no more Mac OS, but Mac OS X. 2. Which Mono version do you use? 3. `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` should be `/` if on Mac OS X, as that's a UNIX variant. If you get \ there must be something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can stay away from DirectorySeparatorChar and let the Mono/.Net framework do the path parsing and combining for you:

```
var appDataDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
Console.WriteLine (appDataDir);
var tempDir = Path.Combine (appDataDir, "temp");
Console.WriteLine (tempDir);
var s = Path.Combine (tempDir, "test.html");
Console.WriteLine (s);
Process.Start (s);
```

If you are on OS-X, that will open "file:///Users/administrator/.config/temp/test.html" in your default browser.

Answer (score 1):

`Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` should return "/" in Linux and OS X and that is the correct way to form path.

Just FYI, `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` should return "\" this.